# IIS 7 Error Page for file with asp Extension

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic

I have tried many ways but unable to do this. I  have set the web.config as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="index.asp">
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I try this url

http://www.aboutmanchester.co.uk/wddwd.asp

It show a message not the error page I mention but when I try

http://www.aboutmanchester.co.uk/wddwd.aspx

I goes to the custom error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the application pool set to 'classic'?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is that an exact web.config copy? Without the errorMode="Custom" attribute on the httpErrors element I only get 404 pages to work with .aspx pages and get a generic IIS error page if I hit a issing .asp page. Adding the attribute gives me the expected behaviour.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
```